# Как отправить данные в уже запущенный Service?

Tags: android, service, android-intent

Как отправить данные в уже работающий сервис?

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClickStart"
        android:text="@string/start">
    </Button>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:text="3" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.my.myapplication;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public final static String BROADCAST_ACTION = "com.example.my.myapplication";

    BroadcastReceiver br;
    EditText EditText1;
    EditText EditText2;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        EditText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        EditText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        // создаем BroadcastReceiver
        br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            // действия при получении сообщений
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                int result = intent.getIntExtra("result", 0);
                String re = Integer.toString(result);
                EditText2.setText(re);
            }
        };
        // создаем фильтр для BroadcastReceiver
        IntentFilter intFilt = new IntentFilter(BROADCAST_ACTION);
        // регистрируем (включаем) BroadcastReceiver
        registerReceiver(br, intFilt);


        Intent intent;

        // Создаем Intent для вызова сервиса,
        // кладем туда параметр времени и код задачи
        int s = Integer.parseInt(EditText1.getText().toString());
        intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class).putExtra("time", s);
        intent.putExtra("time", s);
        // стартуем сервис
        startService(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // дерегистрируем (выключаем) BroadcastReceiver
        unregisterReceiver(br);
    }

    public void onClickStart(View v) {
        Intent intent;
        int s = Integer.parseInt(EditText1.getText().toString());
        intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class).putExtra("time", s);
        intent.putExtra("time", s);
    }

}
```

MyService.java

```
package com.example.my.myapplication;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class MyService extends Service {

    ExecutorService es;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        int time = intent.getIntExtra("time", 1);
        MyRun mr = new MyRun(startId, time);
        es.execute(mr);

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    class MyRun implements Runnable {

        int time;
        int startId;

        public MyRun(int startId, int time) {
            this.time = time;
            this.startId = startId;
        }

        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.BROADCAST_ACTION);
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // начинаем выполнение задачи
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(time);
                    // сообщаем об окончании задачи
                    intent.putExtra("result", time * 100);
                    sendBroadcast(intent);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
           // stop();
        }

        void stop() {
            stopSelfResult(startId);
        }
    }
}
```

Что я хочу от приложения: при запуске стартует сервис, ему отправляется число. Он это число умножает на 100 и отправляет результат в активити во второе текстовое поле (причём продолжает работать дальше). Далее я хочу отправить сервису новое число, не останавливая его работу, ввожу новое число в первое тестовое поле, и при нажатии на кнопку надо отправить сервису это число. А он должен его также умножить на 100 и отправить обратно в активити в первое текстовое поле. Не могу разобраться, как передавать данные уже запущенному сервису. Подскажите.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Запущенный сервис будет работать пока у него не вызван `stopSelf()`. Передавать данные в сервис можно так же с помощью `startService(intent)`, новый сервис запускаться при этом не будет, а у запущенного сервиса будет вызван `onStartCommand`.

Таким образом, вам надо убрать бесконечный цикл из `MyRun.run()`, реализовать логику ваших умножений, убрать `stopSelfResult` из `MyRun.stop()` и добавить `startService(intent);` в `onClickStart` вашей активити.

Чтобы таки потом остановить сервис, запустите его с другим intent'ом, в `onStartCommand` обработайте его: остановите ваш пул или подождите пока он не отработает ([см. тут](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)). Затем вызовите `stopSelf`.

Comment: спасибо, это работает. а как быть, если мне в сервисе нужно запустить 3 задачи почти одновременно? вот такой пример: в сервисе в run осуществляется подключение через сокет к серверу, здесь же создаются 2 объекта: dataToServerStream = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
                dataFromServerStream = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream()); они должны запускаться после подключения к серверу и в разных потоках и работать должны одновременно(чтобы принимать и отправлять данные). можно ли в моем классе сервиса сделать 2 асинктаска и запустить их в run после подключения?

Comment: Сейчас у вас реализовано так, что пока задача не отработает, вторая запускаться не будет: `newFixedThreadPool(1)` (остальные задачи будут висеть в очереди и ждать). Измените 1 на 3 и запускайте сразу по три задачи. Т.е. сервис как сейчас будет принимать по одной задаче, обрабатывая onStartCommand, а пул выполнять будет столько задач одновременно какое число вы ему зададите. Попробуйте.